# add shortcode heading showing multiple time

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi my code is below for adding shortcode in posts. when i am adding shortcode two times it shows me heading two times that i added in code "Recent Posts" is there is way to show this heading only top means one time?

```
/*shortcode start*/
add_shortcode( 'recent-posts', 'PL_recent_posts' );

function PL_recent_posts( $atts  ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'numbers' => '5',
    'order' => 'ASC',

), $atts ) );

$rposts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => $numbers, 'orderby' => 'date' , 'colorss' =>     $color ) );


if ( $rposts->have_posts() ) {
    $html = '<h3>Recent Posts</h3><ul class="recent-posts">';
    while( $rposts->have_posts() ) {
        $rposts->the_post();
        $html .= sprintf(
            '<li><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></li>',
            get_permalink($rposts->post->ID),
            get_the_title(),
            get_the_title()
        );
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
wp_reset_query();

return $html;
}
```

[image: Ecample Image]

Comment: Reformat your code. Place this $html = '<h3>Recent Posts</h3><ul class="recent-posts">'; above if statement

Comment: Can not reproduce the issue. Above code works fine with clean wp installation.

Comment: it is working but the problem is that when I add shortcode in two times "Recent Posts" also display two time like that you see in screen short. what I need. I need to use shortcode multiple time and dont want "Recent Posts" multiple time.

Answer (score 1):

Define a global variable to detect whether title is already added.

```
function PL_recent_posts( $atts ) { 
    global $title_added;
    ...
    if ( $rposts->have_posts() ) {
        if ( $title_added ) {
            $html = '<ul class="recent-posts">';
        } else {
            $html = '<h3>Recent Posts</h3><ul class="recent-posts">';
            $title_added = true;
        }
```

Hope that helps..!